# Save sessions to file in xmonad

Tags: session, xmonad

Is it possible to save an xmonad session to a file and reload it on the fly? I don't want to save only the last session but to be able to save different sessions to different files and reload it if I want.

Comment: If you are using a display manager to log in, could you not create various sessions in that? You can create a few of these, to start programs and end with `exec xmonad`, and then choose the one you want at log in. You can then use xmonad's `manageHook`s to place them in the right arrangement on the right workspace.

Comment: I just stumbled upon [`xmonad-sessions`](https://github.com/zaxtax/xmonad-sessions), a 2-year old try at doing something akin to session mgmt using XMonad.  Haven't tested it, though.  I guess you'd get the best of the bargain with a combination of a lightweight session manager (XFCE's, maybe?) using XMonad for window management.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to start a certain set of program, e.g. everything you need for graphic editing or so, you could just write some little shell script to start those. `manageHook`s can then place the windows in the right workspaces and so on.

This would have the added benefit that you could "restore" multiple settings at once, e.g. chat (pidgin, irssi), browsing (chrome).

The only drawback I see is that you need to manually write your "session files".

Comment: Is there no XMonad persistence similar to Vim's sessions?